# Not able to install CyLP on windows

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install CyLP. I downloaded the cbc package.Then it says to run the following commands:

> $ ./configure
>   $ make
>   $ make install

But these commands do not run in command prompt.So, how do I run them.Also, I tried the following command for pip install:

> pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple cylp

But, it gave me the error that cbc files were not found found.So , how do I install CyLP in windows.

Comment: @Mandy8055 No windows 7

Comment: @V K please check the solution to your question.It will definitely work

Comment: I struggled for ages trying to get `cylp` installed for python 3.6 (required for storageVET) - eventually found suitable wheel file here: https://pypi.org/project/cylp/0.9.0b1/#files - hopefully helps someone else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently worked with `cylp` package but on `linux`. So I am not sure that it is available for windows but there can be a quick fix to this problem on windows.

**For working of make and make install on windows**Here are a few ports of GNU tools to Windows:

**GnuWin32** - http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/summary.html

**Gnu Tools for NT** - http://www.devhood.com/Tools/tool_details.aspx?tool_id=3

**GNU Utilities for Win32** - http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

**For working of ./configure on windows** - I would install the [MINGW/MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/) development tools and see if the configure script is happy in that environment.

**EDIT**

Okay So I finally came up with the solution on how to install CYLP on windows. I would recommend you to:

Try the following

Create a new environment for 32bit Python 2.7:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n py27_32 python=2.7
```

Activate it:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
activate py27_32
```

install cylp:

```
conda install scipy
pip install cylp
```

Comment: I used cygwin, for the purpose, the command ran fine , but then I got the error that c compiler is not acceptable.So, now I am just going to switch to some other library,

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.I am busy these days. So, it will be some time before I try this.